# Understanding the mixed_model () function in R

Tags: r, mixed-model

Even though I already have some experience working with *R* I would still consider myself a beginner. For my current research project, I need to run a **zero-inflated negative binomial regression** with fixed effects. The *mixed_model()* function seems to be the only way to do this in *R*. However, I find the manual to the function very challenging and thus I am looking for some help and explanations here in the community.

I want to run a regression with *violent_events* as the dependent and *project_sum* as the dependent variable. Additionally, I want to control for *gdp*, *population_size* and *education*. My units of analysis are different districts, which can be identified via the *district_id* variable. For each district, I have data for the years 2004 to 2010.

My initial attempt looked like this:

```
gm1 <- mixed_model(violent_events ~ sproject_sum + gdp + population_size + education, 
                   random = year | district_id, data = DF,
                   family = zi.negative.binomial(), zi_fixed = ~ district_id)
```

Of course, the code is not working. I would be grateful for suggestions and particularly explanations that let me understand the *mixed_model()+ function better.

Comment: You can find some explanation about the GLMMadaptive package [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/GLMMadaptive.html). However, as such, this question is off-topic. Is there a specific statistical problem you are having? If so please update your post.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already had a look at this, but find it rather hard to understand. That's why I asked here for a more beginner friendly explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The zero-inflated negative binomial model accounts for "extra" zeros in over-dispersed count outcomes. In particular, it has two components, a negative binomial model and a logistic regression for the extra zeros. The syntax you used above translates to the following specific model,

$$\left \{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\log \{E(\texttt{violent_events}_{ij}) \} & = & \beta_0 + \beta_1 \texttt{sproject_sum}_{ij} + \beta_2 \texttt{gdp}_{ij} + \beta_3 \texttt{population_size}_{ij}\\&& + \beta_4 \texttt{education}_{ij} + b_{i0} + b_{i1} \texttt{time}_{ij}\\&&\\
\Pr\{\mbox{extra } \texttt{violent_events}_{ij} = 0\} & = & \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 \texttt{district_id}_{ij}
\end{array} 
\right.$$

Some notes:

- The term $E(\texttt{violent_events}_{ij})$ denotes the average of the `violent_events` variable. When `violent_events` is zero, then this may be a zero from the negative binomial model or an extra zero with a probability specified by the logistic regression model.
- In the above specification, I do not know if some of the covariates you have are factors with multiple levels (e.g., `district_id`). In this case, their specification expands to multiple coefficients using treatment contrasts.
- In the output, you get the estimated fixed-effects coefficients $\beta_0, \ldots, \beta_4$, and $\gamma_0, \gamma_1$ reported separately.
- In the syntax, you need to include a `~` before the `time` variable in the specification of the `random` argument, i.e., `random = ~ time | district_id`
- Given that `district_id` is a grouping variable, you would need to put a random effect for it in the logistic regression part, i.e., `zi_random = ~ 1 | district_id`, and most probably you do not want to include it as a fixed effect, i.e., `zi_fixed = ~ 1`. If you do that, then in the equation above, you will have an extra random effect $u_i$ in the logistic regression part, and the random effects $b_{0i}$, $b_{1i}$, and $u_{i}$ will be assumed to be correlated.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I received: `Error in mixed_model... : you have defined a family with an extra zero-part;at least argument 'zi_fixed' needs to be defined, and potentially also argument 'zi_random'.` 
My model looked like this: 
`gm1 <- mixed_model(violent_events ~ sproject_sum + gdp + population_size + education, random = ~ year | distict_id, data = TC, family = zi.negative.binomial(), zi_random = ~ 1 | district_id, zi_fixed = NULL)`

Comment: If I add zi_random = `~ 1` i get `Error in chol.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
  the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite`

Comment: You may need to simplify the random effects structure for the negative binomial part, e.g., `random = ~ 1 | district_id`. And, you also need `zi_fixed = ~ 1`.

Comment: Then I receive `Error in mixed_fit(y, X, Z, X_zi, Z_zi, id, offset, offset_zi, family,  : 
  A large coefficient value has been detected during the optimization.
 Please re-scale you covariates and/or try setting the control argument
 'iter_EM = 0'. Alternatively, this may due to a
 divergence of the optimization algorithm, indicating that an overly
 complex model is fitted to the data. For example, this could be
 caused when including random-effects terms (e.g., in the
 zero-inflated part) that you do not need. Otherwise, adjust the
 'max_coef_value' control argument.`